# Bundle in onActivityCreated() returns null, even after setting values in onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a application whenever a **fragment** loses focus (i.e. another activity / fragment is opened over it), it's `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.

Same is mentioned in [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

I'm trying to use this approch to maintain the state of my fragment whenever it is resumed.
My intention was to call this `bundle` in `onActivityCreated()`, when the fragment is resumed.

Although `onSaveInstanceState` is called before fragment losing focus.
But, when `onActivityCreated()` is called it recives the `Bundle savedInstanceState` as null.

How can I fetch the data from the bundle.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.my_row, titles, icons, this);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Never goes inside this condiiton.
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}
```

Comment: try some log.v methods, and send the logcat. This will show where the program switches

Comment: there is one more way you can use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Is it erroring all the time, or just the first time you open the application?

Comment: Dont want to shared prefs, there is lots of data to store in bundle. @Otra it is giving null everytime

Answer (score 0):

Then it means that your activity and fragment were just paused and did not have to save their instance state (`onSaveInstanceState()` is not necessarily called).

If you want to make sure `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, select "Don't keep activities" in the device's developer settings. Then each time an activity is paused, the system kills it forcing the call to `onSaveInstanceState()` (except when you just press back of course)

Comment: No, on debugging `onSaveInstanceState()` is getting called. Updated my question